# Javascript url load and retrieve parameters - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present error

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to fetch parameters from URL response. when I call the URL from the browser I get the following response

Request : http:///api/mail_ru/scan.json?api_key=SgJEE8ZMUmpJ66lLfKTjxpbcsdI3cIml&domain=

Response : {"status":"started","uid":"9aa342-91ca-4d8d-90cf-941c38a7"}

Now I have to call the URL using javascript and retrieve only uid value. I'm using below code but getting following error. Please help.

The error is: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

The code is as follows...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://<Actual URL>/api/mail_ru/scan.json?api_key=SgJEE8ZMUmpJ66lLfKTjxpbcsdI3cIml&domain=<search URL>,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) { 
            var outputuid = data.uid;
            alert(outputuid);
        },
        error: function(data) { alert("Failed"); },
      });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" hidden="true"> </div>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="URL" value=""></p>
<button>Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this code in an HTML file and I'm executing it from different browsers and getting the same error. I browsed about this error and it says, it is related to CORS but didn't mention what piece of code need to be added to the above-mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  <script>
    jQuery(function() {
      // Hook the button click
      jQuery("#theButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url:"http:///api/mail_ru/scan.json?api_key=SgJEE8ZMUmpJ66lLfKTjxpbcsdI3cIml&domain=",
          success:function(response){
            jQuery(response. uid).appendTo(document.body);
          }
        })

      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Ahmed, it didn't work for me. I updated my initial question with more details. Can anyone help?

Comment: this error is related to server side , what is your server side programming language ?? ... you should put this in server side header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");